# как вывести данные с помощью связной таблицы Yii2?

Tags: yii2

Не могу понять, как эти связи работают, и смысл их вообще. Еслить 3 таблицы **category, article, cat_article**

> ```html
> class Category extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
> {
>     /**
>      * {@inheritdoc}
>      */
>     public static function tableName()
>     {
>         return '{{%category}}';
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * {@inheritdoc}
>      */
>     public function rules()
>     {
>         return [
>             [['id', 'name', 'parent_id'], 'required'],
>             [['id', 'parent_id'], 'integer'],
>             [['name', 'description', 'keywords'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
>             [['id'], 'unique'],
>         ];
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * {@inheritdoc}
>      */
>     public function attributeLabels()
>     {
>         return [
>             'id' => 'ID',
>             'name' => 'Name',
>             'parent_id' => 'Parent ID',
>             'description' => 'Description',
>             'keywords' => 'Keywords',
>         ];
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Gets query for [[CatArticles]].
>      *
>      * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
>      */
>     public function getCatArticles()
>     {
>         return $this->hasMany(CatArticle::class, ['category_id' => 'id']);
>     }
> ```

> ```html
> class ForecastArticle extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
> {
>     public static function tableName()
>     {
>         return '{{%forecast_article}}';
>     }
>
>     public function rules()
>     {
>         return [
>             [['title', 'text', 'percent'], 'required'],
>             [['description', 'text'], 'string'],
>             [['coef'], 'number'],
>             [['status'], 'integer'],
>             [['created_at', 'updated_at'], 'safe'],
>             [['title', 'desc_title', 'image'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
>             [['percent'], 'string', 'max' => 10],
>         ];
>     }
>
>
>     public function attributeLabels()
>     {
>         return [
>             'id' => 'ID',
>             'title' => 'Title',
>             'description' => 'Description',
>             'desc_title' => 'Desc Title',
>             'text' => 'Text',
>             'image' => 'Image',
>             'coef' => 'Coef',
>             'percent' => 'Percent',
>             'status' => 'Status',
>             'created_at' => 'Created At',
>             'updated_at' => 'Updated At',
>         ];
>     }
>
>
>     public function getCatArticles()
>     {
>         return $this->hasMany(CatArticle::class, ['article_id' => 'id']);
>     }
>
>     public function getTagsForecastArts()
>     {
>         return $this->hasMany(TagsForecastArt::class, ['article_id' => 'id']);
>     }
>
>     public function getUserForecastArts()
>     {
>         return $this->hasMany(UserForecastArt::class, ['article_id' => 'id']);
>     }
> ```

> ```html
> class CatArticle extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
> {
>
>     public static function tableName()
>     {
>         return '{{%cat_article}}';
>     }
>
>
>     public function rules()
>     {
>         return [
>             [['category_id', 'article_id'], 'required'],
>             [['category_id', 'article_id'], 'integer'],
>             [['article_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => ForecastArticle::class, 'targetAttribute' => ['article_id' => 'id']],
>             [['category_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Category::class, 'targetAttribute' => ['category_id' => 'id']],
>         ];
>     }
>
>
>     public function attributeLabels()
>     {
>         return [
>             'category_id' => 'Category ID',
>             'article_id' => 'Article ID',
>         ];
>     }
>
>
>     public function getArticle()
>     {
>         return $this->hasMany(ForecastArticle::class, ['id' => 'article_id']);
>     }
>
>
>     public function getCategory()
>     {
>         return $this->hasMany(Category::class, ['id' => 'category_id']);
>     }
> ```

Делаю запрос

```html
public function actionView($id){
    $category = Category::findOne($id);
    if(empty($category)){
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('Такой категории нет.....');
    }
    $art = CatArticle::find()->where(['category_id' => $id])->all();
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($art);
    echo '</pre>';
    return $this->render('view');
}
```

**$art** выводится как надо, но достучаться до связных данных не могу....Может что то не так делаю конечно...Обьясните нормальным языком. Дока тоже не помогла. За ранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Значит плохо читали. Без знания связей никуда.

В вашем случае используется связь **многие ко многим(many-to-many)** - обе стороны могут относиться к нескольким экземплярам другой стороны. Сделано у вас через промежуточную таблицу, значит мы можем использовать метод `viaTable`:

```
# Category.php
...
public function getArticles()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Article::className(), ['id' => 'article_id'])
        ->viaTable('cat_article', ['category_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Далее используете отталкиваясь от потребностей ([with](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequerytrait#with()-detail), `$category->articles`).

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался кое как)